# Why isn't this java interface definition using generics accepted by the compiler?

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to understand why the compiler complains about this interface declaration.  T is a generic type parameter.

```
static class Bar<T extends Comparable<?>> {}
static interface Foo<T extends Comparable<?>, Bar<T>> { }
```

The compiler says

`Error:(64, 53) Groovyc: unexpected token: <`

(64, 53) is the `<` before the second `T`.

What I'd like is to have an interface Foo that works with instances of Bar that contain any class that extends Comparable.

Comment: the identifier `static` is unnecessary there and if your class is called `Foo` as you've stated then surely your interface cannot be called `Foo` as well (considering they're in the same packages).

Comment: Pretty sure T has to be defined (`T extends Comparable<?>`) the first time its used, so `Foo<T extends Comparable<?>, Bar<T>>`. Not posting as an answer because I'm not 100% certain, I've done too much switching back & forth between Java and C#.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If Bar is a concrete class, why do you declare it as a generic type of the Foo interface?

Comment: The class `Bar` is not used in the interface definition. It is hidden by the generic type parameter named `Bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I'd like is to have an interface Foo that works with instances of Bar that contain any class that extends Comparable.

Then Bar should be generic, and the interface should just be parameterized on T:

```
class Bar<T> {...}

interface Foo<T extends Comparable<?>> {
    Bar<T> doSomething(Bar<T> otherBar);
    ...
}
```

Or, if you also want Foo to be generic on a type that extends Bar, then it should be something like

```
interface Foo<T extends Comparable<?>, B extends Bar<T>> {
    B doSomething(B otherBar);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove bar part from interface definition. That syntax only makes sense when you do extend or implements. Here are examples:

```
static interface SuperFoo<T1, T2>{}

static interface SubFoo<T extends Comparable<?> > extends SuperFoo< T, Bar<T> >{}
```

I guess in your case this is what you wanted to do:

```
static interface Bar<F>{}

static interface Foo< T extends Comparable<?> > { 

    public void handle( Bar<T> bar );

}
```